# Accessing group variable in template file of role belonging to another group

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Inventory file:

```
[1]
IP

[2]
IP

[1:vars]
foo=test
```

How can I access variable `foo` in role which will be executed on group [2]?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot name host groups with a single digit, so fix the inventory file:

```
[group1]
IP1

[group2]
IP2

[group1:vars]
foo=test
```

Then when running against `group2`, to access the variable defined for `group1`, use the following construct:

```
- debug:
    var: hostvars[groups['group1'][0]]['foo']
```

Generally, I would try to avoid such references though.

Comment: I had given host groups with a single digit just as reference/sample.

Comment: Why should we avoid such references? Wouldn't it be better to have one source of truth instead of duplicating a value in different groups?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter where the variable come from (inventory,playbook,extras), you access it by name, like:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ foo }}"
```

If variable with the same name is defined in multiple places, the one with higher precedence wins (see [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)).

Comment: If you run this task with `- hosts: group1` you won't be able to access the variable `foo` no? Only hosts of group2 will have foo defined. Can you tell me if I'm wrong ?